# Should brakes lock when hit hard?

Tags: ford, braking

I drive a 2011 Ford Fusion SEL. If relevant, I've noticed by seeing through the wheels that it's 4 wheel disc-brakes.

I used to drive a 2003 Mazda Protege DX. When I hit the brakes hard in that vehicle my wheels would lock up. However, in my Fusion I've noticed that when hit the brakes hard (and I could be doing only like 25-30 MPH) that my brakes don't "lock". At that speed, if I hit my brakes hard I feel like the car should basically come to a complete stop right stop. It's not doing that. It keeps moving and slows down, I don't know for certain but it feels like it could be 10 feet or so before a stop.

Note I'm not talking about ABS kicking in because of lack of traction.

Is this normal on newer cars or should I get my brakes checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the newer Ford is not stopping as quickly as the Mazda did, I recommend you get it checked.

The ABS on newer cars might be smoother so you're not noticing it, but stopping distance should be at least on par with the older car.

Comment: I think I'll take it in to get them checked and check back at this post after.

Answer (score 3):

Even high performance cars can't stop on a penny - the brakes have to do work and turn the kinetic energy in to heat. There will be a maximum rate at which this work can be done - if you fitted bigger, more powerful brakes then these in turn, would put a greater load on the tyres and demand more from the suspension too (the suspension has to put weight on the tyres in order to produce the friction required for the tyres to push against the road and slow the car).

The distance you mention sounds perfectly safe for that speed.

Having said all that, if you are concerned that something is wrong, take it to a ford dealer or a mechanic and ask them to check it. It's a possible safety concern after all.